# Error installing Gluon Eclpse Plugin 2.4.0 on Eclipse Neon JEE

Tags: eclipse, gluon

I nedd help to solve an installation error of Eclipse Gluon Plugin that is reported when installing latest Gluon 2.4.0 plugin on Eclipse Neon. I have searched StackOverflow and read the Gluon installation docs but I cannot see what's wrong.

The Gluon Plugin does not appear when I search in Eclipse MarketPlace, so I installed it by adding the Gluon and e(fx)clipse sites manually.

On my "Available Sofware Sites" I added:

- e(fx)clipse 2.3.0 site http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.3.0/site which is a dependency of Gluon (although latest e(fx)clipse is 2.4.0)
- Gluon site http://download.gluonhq.com/tools/eclipse/release

The Gluon Tools 2.4.0 and e(fx)clipse shows up in the Available software list, however when I intall them I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gluonhq.ide-plugin-templates,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.freemarker,2.3.19
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.glassfish.javax.json,1.0.4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Gluon plugin from the MarketPlace, but in two steps:

The first step, when you open the MarketPlace and search for Gluon, it shows you there are no results, but it allows you keep on searching:

[image: marketPlace]

Click on the link to open the marketplace in a tab:

[image: Browser]

Now you can click on the Install button to proceed with the plugin installation.

It will show the Marketplace again, so click on the link `One solution selected`. In your case, it should show an Install button.

[image: Plugin]

Comment: Hi José, thanks for replying. I used the procedure you indicate to install from MarketPlace but at the end of the installation I get exaclty the same error:

Comment: I've just installed e(fx)clipse and the gluon plugin, and I've done the whole process all over again. It works fine for me.

Comment: I am running under Windows 7 64 bits, your screenshots are from a Mac. Have you tried on a Windows?

Comment: I installed a fresh version of Eclipse 64bits (now Oxygen) and I have the same issue: 
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.gluonhq.ide-plugin-templates,2.4.0,,,

Comment: Yes, I've also installed the plugin on Windows, on a new fresh installation of Eclipse Neon 2

Comment: Which Eclipse package did you use? I am using Eclipse JEE 32 bits, I would like to try with your exact configuration.

Comment: Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2), Build id: 20161208-0600, downloaded from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R2a/eclipse-inst-win64.exe)

Answer (score 0):

After installing Eclipse with the windows .exe installer I can now successfully install the Gluon plugin.

I can even install now the Gluon plugin in my original faulty Eclipse installation which was based on one a downloadable .zip JEE package.

Eclipse uses hidden .p2 and .m2 directories under user home folder, I suspect that something was corrupted on my installation. After running the .exe installer has updated the %HOMEPATH%.p2\pool directory and now is working fine.

Thanks for the help José, and thanks for writting and sharing those good JavaFX tutorials in your blog!